# Copy files and only the parent folder the file resides

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Copying files but not all the folders, just the one parent/relative folder in which contains the files.

**Folder and Files structure:**

1. ExcelData (Folder)

   a. File1.xlsx

   b. File2.xlsx

   c. File3.xlsx

   d. File14.xlsx

   e. File15.xlsx

**Code I'm using:**

```
$sourcePath = '\\171.168.10.98\One_Data'
$destinationPath = 'C:\Temp'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse
$filecount = $files.count
$i=0
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $i++
    Write-Progress -activity "copying files..." -status "($i of $filecount) $file" -percentcomplete (($i/$filecount)*100)
  
    # Determine the absolute path of this object's parent container.  This is stored as a different attribute on file and folder objects so we use an if block to cater for both
    if ($file.psiscontainer) {$sourcefilecontainer = $file.parent} else {$sourcefilecontainer = $file.directory}

    # Calculate the path of the parent folder relative to the source folder
    $relativepath = $sourcefilecontainer.fullname.SubString($sourcepath.length)

    # Copy the object to the appropriate folder within the destination folder
    copy-Item $file.fullname ($destinationPath + $relativepath)
}
```

Comment: Please add your question. As it is now, we do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `$includes` array with the files comma separated and double quote enclosed. Use the `-Include` parameter of the `Get-ChildItem` command and use the `$includes` array as the value it uses. Use `.Split("\")[-2]` to get only the folder  which the file resides, and use that with the `new-item` command to create that folder in the destination if it does not already exist. Lastly, use the same `.Split("\")[-2]` with the `copy-item` command to copy the file into that directory in the destination location.

### PowerShell

```
$includes = "File1.xlsx","File14.xlsx";
$sourcePath = '\\171.168.10.98\One_Data';
$destinationPath = 'C:\Temp';
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -Include $includes; 
$filecount = $files.count;
$i=0;

Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $i++;
    Write-Progress -activity "copying files..." -status "($i of $filecount) $file" -percentcomplete (($i/$filecount)*100);
    If (!(Test-Path "$($destinationPath)\$(($file.FullName).Split("\")[-2])")){New-Item "$($destinationPath)\$(($file.FullName).Split("\")[-2])" -Type Directory -Force;};
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination "$($destinationPath)\$(($file.FullName).Split("\")[-2])" -Force;
    };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

Comment: Thanks this is what I want. But the progress bar is missing which is in my code. Please include that as well.

Comment: There is no other issue. Only progress bar is required which validate either all file copied or not.